# How can I store reagent under inert gas?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, reagents

I need to store some aliquots of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene. I searched for how to store reagent under inert gas, And I found this : https://avantilipids.com/tech-support/faqs/protect-from-oxidation

In summary, it says:

1. aliquot the reagent as desired into vial.
2. blow a gentle stream of inert gas into the vial for few seconds.
3. cap and seal the vial and store in fridge.

Is this enough? Somehow I feel that this method is a little bit clumsy. Does really just blowing inert gas few seconds ensure inert atmosphere?

Comment: It depends on how carefully it is done. And depending on the way you close the vial, the cap, etc. I can't write an answer for this. But consider asking a colleague to be there for quick action. Longer you bubble better it is. Ar is better than N2. Etc. Or a vacuum/inert line is on place and a branch of it is for storage. For prolonged storage or relatively small sample vials of thin glass ready to be molten-sealed do exist (nothing expensive, just glass "bubble" with a thin open input. You can purge them through a needle using Ar and quickly seal. Think of the vials for injection drugs

Comment: This particular compound will solidify; not on bench, but in the fridge. Beside the larger effect by temperature, this equally will lower a bit the rate of decomposition. Don't forget to put a legible label on the container.